# pointerEvents = "none" not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a memory card game and it works until I try to click on the cards too fast. When I open two cards, I am calling `compareCards` function which adds  `document.body.style.pointerEvents = "none";` but obviously I can click on the third card if I am fast enough. How can I fix it? Here is my full JS code, note that class `.flip` adds  `pointer-events: none;` among other things while `.match` adds short animation. I guess it probably has something to do with setTimeouts but I need them in order to show animatioins.

```
const playBtn = document.querySelector(".intro button");
const restartBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".restartBtn");
const introScreen = document.querySelector(".intro");
const game = document.querySelector(".game");

const gameContainer = document.querySelector("#gameContainer");

const timer = document.querySelector(".timer span");
const moves = document.querySelector(".moves span");
let time,
  minutes = 0,
  seconds = 0;
let numberOfMoves = 0;
moves.innerHTML = numberOfMoves;

let openCards = [];
let matchedCards = [];

function startGame() {
  let shuffledDeck = shuffle(deckCards);

  for (let i = 0; i < shuffledDeck.length; i++) {
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    card.classList.add("card");
    const image = document.createElement("img");

    image.setAttribute("src", "img/" + shuffledDeck[i]);

    card.appendChild(image);
    gameContainer.appendChild(card);
  }
  runTimer();
}

const deckCards = [
... images to add to game ...];

gameContainer.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (e.target.className === "card") {
    flipCard();
  }
  function flipCard() {
    e.target.classList.add("flip");
    addCard();
  }

  function addCard() {
    if (openCards.length == 0 || openCards.length == 1) {
      openCards.push(e.target.firstElementChild);
    }

    compareCards();
  }
});

function compareCards() {
  if (openCards.length == 2) {
    document.body.style.pointerEvents = "none";
  }

  if (openCards[0].src == openCards[1].src && openCards.length == 2) {
    cardsMatched();
  } else if (openCards[0].src !== openCards[1].src && openCards.length == 2) {
    cardsNotMatched();
  }
}

function countMoves() {
  numberOfMoves++;
  moves.innerHTML = numberOfMoves;
}

function cardsMatched() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    openCards[0].parentElement.classList.add("match");
    openCards[1].parentElement.classList.add("match");
    matchedCards.push(...openCards);
    document.body.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
    gameWon();
    openCards = [];
  }, 500);
  countMoves();
}

function cardsNotMatched() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    openCards[0].parentElement.classList.remove("flip");
    openCards[1].parentElement.classList.remove("flip");
    document.body.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
    openCards = [];
  }, 500);
  countMoves();
}

function gameWon() {
  if (matchedCards.length == 16) {
    stopTimer();
    showModal();
  }
}
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
function showModal() {
  const closeModal = document.querySelector(".closeBtn");
  modal.style.display = "block";
  closeModal.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  });
  window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  };
}

function resetEverything() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  stopTimer();
  timer.innerHTML = `00:00`;
  numberOfMoves = 0;
  moves.innerHTML = numberOfMoves;
  matchedCards = [];
  openCards = [];
  startGame();
}

function shuffle(array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length,
    randomIndex;

  while (currentIndex != 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;

    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex],
      array[currentIndex],
    ];
  }

  return array;
}

function runTimer() {
  time = setInterval(() => {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds == 60) {
      minutes++;
      seconds = 0;
    }
    timer.innerHTML = `${minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes}:${
      seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds
    }`;
  }, 1000);
}

function stopTimer() {
  seconds = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  clearInterval(time);
}

playBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  introScreen.classList.remove("fadeIn");
  introScreen.classList.add("fadeOut");
  game.classList.add("fadeIn");
  startGame();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're running into is a common problem where it takes time for things like CSS to propagate through the website, especially when you have timeouts. What you should do is VERY RARELY rely on CSS classes for your logic and let CSS be what it's meant to be: a purely visual medium.

The solution is simple. Instead of relying on pointer events, set up a flag that toggles whether the user is allowed to click on something or not, and then reference that flag for all your logic. This allows you to decouple what you see from what's happening underneath the hood. Something like this (only the relevant bits):

```
let canAction = true; // add a flag

function startGame() {
  // ... start game logic
  canAction = true; // set the flag to allow actions
}

gameContainer.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (canAction) {
    // ... card click logic
  }
});

function compareCards() {
  if (openCards.length == 2) {
    canAction = false; // stop user from taking further action
  }
  
  // ... rest of compare card logic
}

function cardsMatched() {
  canAction = true; // re allow the user to click on cards - put this inside the setTimeout or outside depending on what you need
  setTimeout(function () {
    // ...
  }, 500);
  countMoves();
}

function cardsNotMatched() {
  canAction = true; // re allow the user to click on cards - put this inside the setTimeout or outside depending on what you need
  setTimeout(function () {
    // ...
  }, 500);
  countMoves();
}
```

Of course you are free to keep the pointer-events CSS stuff as well, but don't rely on it for your logic. You'll just be inviting a whole lot of messy situations like this.